# Public Activity - Creating activities based on certain attribute changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, public-activity

I'm using the Rails gem, Public Activity and wanted to create an activity instance for every `update` action but with a catch. I only want the event created if a certain attribute is changed. In my case it would be a post's `time_zone`. Here is how activities are currently created in my posts controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    ...
    @post.create_activity :update, owner: current_user
    ...
  end
end
```

I couldn't find anything in the docs that explain how to do the aforementioned. Is there a way to setup, let's say a conditional that checks if the `time_zone` has changed to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ActiveModel::Dirty`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) handles tracking changes to attributes in your model. There are a number of ways to tell whether or not a specific attribute did change:

- [`changed_attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-changed_attributes) returns a `Hash` of model changes before save (meaning it is `{}` after a save because you have a clear, unchanged state for the current object). That won't work in your controller.
- [`previous_changes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-previous_changes) returns a `Hash` of attributes that were changed by a save. **This is what you want for your controller.**

So, you need the following in your controller

```
def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.update!(post_params)

  if @post.previous_changes.key?('time_zone')
    @post.create_activity(:update, owner: current_user)
  end
end
```

Comment: Would you perhaps share some details please